# Risk management for Digital Option at large Bank

Tags: delta-hedging, exotics, binary-options

Say, an investment bank sell Digital Call Option to its client at strike 100.
But trader at the bank want to book the deal with a call spread at 99/100 (price&hedge Digital Option like price&hedge a call spread) because trader believe that it will help smoothing hedging.

How should risk manager at the bank measure the risk?

1. a digital option as it is an actual contingent obligation?
2. or a call spread as it is what trader book the deal?

Comment: Risks and hedging go along, both should be based on what is actually in the books (here the call spread). Actually this call-spread 99/100 cost more than the digital feature you're selling to your client, so it could be seen as digital + margin.

Comment: @Quantuple Does this work other way around, if client instead writes Digital Option, bank will pay more (-margin) if bank book digital option as call spread?

Comment: It's always the same. You book what you buy/sell. Then the prices and hedges are determined based on your in house models. The idea being that you should incorporate a margin to your price, margin that you'll try to defend by hedging properly. Although it's a pretty long read I suggest you have a look at https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2365294

Comment: @jackgurae, If client sells the digital , you book a 100-101 call spread.

Comment: What if strike of digital is at 26.76.  Payoff is either 1 or nothig. Given that tick size around this price range is 0.25. How would I set up a call spread? 26.50/26.76 would require about 4x leverage (buy at 26.50 and sell at 26.76). But in practice I can use only 2x leverage (buy at 26.50 and sell at 27.00)